# Prove $\forall a>0.BPP[{a,a+\frac{1}{n}}]=BPP$

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, chernoff-bounds

I need to prove that

$\forall a>0.BPP[{a,a+\frac{1}{n}}]=BPP$

$BPP[a,b]$ [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP_(complexity)):

> A language `L` is in `BPP(a,b)` if and only if there exists a
>   probabilistic Turing machine `M`, such that
>
> `M` runs for polynomial time on all inputs For all `x` in `L`, `M`
>   outputs `1` with probability greater than or equal to `b` For all `x`
>   not in `L`, `M` outputs `1` with probability less than or equal to `a`

I've tried using the `Amplifying Lemmas` and then `Chernoff Inequality`, when my sketch of proof was to run the probabilistic Turing Machine on the input $k$, times and then accept or reject according to majority of accepting or rejecting of the simulated runs.

My problem is with the choosing of $k$. No value that I chose could work with the lower and upper bounds.

Am I in the right direction? Could I get a tip regarding $k$?

Comment: Please include a definition for $\mathsf{BPP}\left(x,y\right)$.

Comment: @Ariel - added definition